# Unable to store as CCyy-mm-dd format in .csv file generated by linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, csv, date

I am trying to store CCyy-mm-dd format date in csv file via Unix, but when i open the csv file the century is taken as year for example if I want to store 2118-07-19 it is getting displayed as 19-07-2118 when I open csv file

Comment: How do you write the date into the file? And how do you open it, in a text editor or spreadsheet application?

Comment: while read line

do

a=`date +'%y-%m-%d' -d $line`

#append century

echo "21"$a>>dum2.txt

done<dum1.txt

 

echo "GLBL,DATE">OADR_SE_GLBL.csv

paste -d, objids.txt dum2.txt>>OADR_SE_GLBL.csv

Comment: You should edit the question and add the code there

Comment: Why do you use `%y` and add the date by string concatenation, instead of simply using `%Y`?

Comment: Anyway, the output from `date` should be fine. When you say "it gets displayed as...", _where_ is it displayed? Are you using a spreadsheet application?

Comment: Yes im using Microsoft Excel to view the generated csv file

Comment: Then this is just the way Excel displays the date. You would have to change this in the CSV import of Excel or the cell formatting. So this question is not about Linux, but Excel. You could change your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a specific order for your desired command

```
 date +"%m-%d-%y" > yourOutput.csv
```